# Facebook no longer picking up *any* meta data from my WP blog

Tags: facebook, wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I've been running a blog for years now, and sharing blog posts (with the correct thumbnail, title and description) on Facebook always worked fine. Last week however, when sharing new blog posts, all the meta data was obviously missing - Facebook didn't even pick up the title of the page. When debugging the new blog posts, I get:

```
Response Code : 503

Missing Required Property:  The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:title property is required, but not present.
```

-for http://www.discodemons.net/2012/02/16/moullinex-peaches-maniac/

When debugging old posts (and by old I mean posts published before that day when Facebook suddenly decided to stop reading meta data from my site), everything's there, I can share the link with picture, thumbnail and description.

There are two things troubling me:

1) I have all important meta tags explicitly specified in my header and my functions.php - when viewing the source code for the blog posts (see for yourself here: http://www.discodemons.net/2012/02/16/moullinex-peaches-maniac/
 ) , everything's there. I didn't change anything on my blog for weeks (or maybe months), and yet, from one day to another, I can't share my links on Facebook correctly anymore - even though all the required meta data is there.

2) Facebook is able to pull title, image etc. from even the most simple sites, that don't have any meta data included. I've tried and removed all the meta data from the header and functions.php, and yet facebook couldn't pull any information from my site?!

I've tried disabling all comments, tested some WP plugins that put the correct meta data in your source code, disabled them again, even removed all FB-related plugins such as like/sharing button etc. Any help on this much appreciated, I haven't got a clue how I could possibly fix this!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your WP server is returning a 503 server error for all scrapes from Facebook. It may be that this is a security feature you enabled recently, or a plugin that attempts to serve different content to Facebook for the purposes of scraping.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't change any security options recently, neither do I have any plug-ins installed that might cause this. Do you have any idea what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Try contacting your hosting provider and see if there are any rules at their end that might be causing this. Also, try hitting the same URL from a number of different sources. Pingdom Tools offers a useful way to test this (http://tools.pingdom.com).